# Set different width of item in a GridView

Tags: android, android-gridview

I want to set different widths of every item in a **GridView**. My requirement is how to set the item width in a GridView in which we can remove the extra space under the red arrow and set different number of item in every row. Also if the item is too long like under the green arrow set only one item in a row. How Can I achieve this? Right now I have a custom item layout in which a TextView and a Button is set into a GridView by using BaseAdapter.

If there is any another way instead of a GridView will also helpful.

[image: **Screen Shoot of GridView**]

Comment: You can't do that with a simple `GridView`. You'll need to make your own implementation, which would not be something easy to do.Maybe you can find something already built out there.